# AuthorizationHeaderMalformed when trying to upload object to S3 via JS SDK

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I’m trying to upload an object to Amazon S3 via their JavaScript SDK, but getting the following error during the upload:

```xml
<Error>
    <Code>AuthorizationHeaderMalformed</Code>
    <Message>The authorization header is malformed; the region 'us-east-1' is wrong; expecting 'eu-west-1'</Message>
    <Region>eu-west-1</Region>
    <RequestId>62D2D18E5093BF1D</RequestId>
    <HostId>87ixJCkZyInIVI9BH4zdxtNzFuydwByK6ibvXOICXoE6ZQMp+lWf9RxetaL9c5qFEZEWW/RYdFQ=</HostId>
</Error>
```

I get this error response when a HTTP request to https://my-bucket-name.s3.amazonaws.com/?max-keys=0 is made.

I’ve tried setting the region everywhere, but still getting the error.

Here’s what my code instantiating the S3 client looks like:

```js
import AWS from 'aws-sdk';

AWS.config.update({
    region: 'eu-west-1',
    credentials: new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials({
        IdentityPoolId: this.identityPoolId
    }, {
        region: 'eu-west-1'
    })
});

this.s3 = new AWS.S3({
    apiVersion: '2006-03-01',
    params: {
        Bucket: this.bucket
    },
    region: 'eu-west-1'
});
```

Where am I going wrong? Why is there still a reference to `us-east-1` in the above error response when generating the signature?

EDIT: I’ve written and re-written the set-up code a few times over now. This is what I currently have:

```js
const AWS = require('aws-sdk/global');
const S3 = require('aws-sdk/clients/s3');

this.s3 = new S3({
    apiVersion: 'latest',
    credentials: new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials({
        IdentityPoolId: this.identityPoolId
    }, {
        region: 'eu-west-1'
    }),
    params: {
        Bucket: this.bucket
    },
    region: 'eu-west-1'
});
```

And then the code that does the actual file upload:

```js
const params = {
    ACL: 'private',
    Body: this.file,
    ContentType: this.file.type,
    Key: `videos/input/${this.filename}`
};

this.s3
    .putObject(params)
    .on('httpUploadProgress', this.onUploadProgress)
    .send(this.onSend);
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is caused by your call to `CognitoIdentityCredentials` The variable AWS is not setup yet.

Change your code to look like this:

```
AWS.config.region = 'eu-west-1';
AWS.config.credentials = new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials({
    IdentityPoolId: this.identityPoolId
});
```

Comment: I’ve done that, but still getting the error. I also changed `import AWS from 'aws-sdk'` to `var AWS = require('aws-sdk')`. Am I still doing something wrong? I just don’t understand where it’s getting 'us-east-1' from!

Comment: Add you new modified code at the bottom of your question (don't change the existing code in the question as this makes a mess of things). What is the default region that you setup for the AWS CLI (~/.aws/credentials)? Run "aws configure" in a command prompt. Press ENTER to keep the current value.

Comment: It’s running in a Heroku web dyno, but I have an `AWS_DEFAULT_REGION` environment variable set to `eu-west-1`.

Comment: Do you have the credentials file setup? If not I don't think that AWS_DEFAULT_REGION will have any effect. The SDK will first look at the environment variables, but if they are not all set, then it moves to profiles and then roles until it finds a set of valid credentials to use. I think that you have an issue in this provider chain and the fallback is the default region us-east-1. However, if you implemented my code change correctly, then this will be overridden. Post your complete code so that I can see.

Answer (score 1):

When you get this error it means that the bucket name you have chosen exists somewhere else on Amazon S3, this could be in your account or in another account.

Since S3 uses a single namespace all bucket names have to be unique. If this bucket exists inside your account update your script to point to the actual region where the bucket exists. If it's not in your account then change the bucket name and give it a go.